# Material Design Lite *ngIf on Form Input Field Angular 5

Tags: forms, input, angular5, material-design-lite

I want to build some dynamic form fields.
When I put an *ngIf in fron of the div the material design does not work properly (no effects etc.).

Here is the input field that works

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="number" id="playerCount" [(ngModel)]="playerCount" (ngModelChange)="setPlayerCount(playerCount)">
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="playerCount">Anzahl Spieler</label>
</div>
```

and the one that does not work

```
<div *ngIf="players" class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="stuff">
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="stuff">stuff</label>
</div>
```

The second div should appear as soon as the first has been filled out.

[image]

Comment: After adding 
declare var componentHandler: any;  
before the component you can call
    componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();
which does the trick just like zfor said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register new elements to MDL's `componentHandler` since *ngIf actually removes the element from the dom, you have to register that element every time Angular removes/inserts it.
You can either call `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered();` every time *ngIf inserts the element or replace *ngIf with something that is just hides the element but not remove it.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, I am now trying to figure out how to import the MDL componenthandler. Any advise on that too ?